# Populating a DataFrame from 2 other DataFrames

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, dataframe, merge

I have been trying to combine the information from 2 dataframes into a single new dataframe without luck. I have searched extensively, but still can't find any relevant answer, so apologies if I have missed it in my search.

When creating an investing strategy, among a large set of currencies (more than 50) I have picked the top 5 currencies to invest in for every date (in *top_n.csv*) and their respective % weight to invest for each currency on each date (in *weights.csv*).

*top_n.csv* lools like:

```
Date               0         1         2      3        4
Aug 12, 2016    bitcoin  ethereum   0        0        0
Aug 11, 2016    bitcoin  ethereum   ripple  steem     litecoin
Aug 10, 2016    bitcoin  ethereum   ripple  0         0
Aug 09, 2016    bitcoin  ethereum   steem   ripple    ethereum-classic
```

*weights.csv* lools like:

```
Date               0      1        2      3       4
Aug 12, 2016    0.859   0.089   nan     nan     nan
Aug 11, 2016    0.856   0.092   0.020   0.016   0.016
Aug 10, 2016    0.853   0.093   0.020   nan     nan
Aug 09, 2016    0.858   0.086   0.020   0.020   0.017
```

The DataFrame which I am trying to populate is one which contains same dates (in the index), but has a number of columns corresponding to a larger set of coins (more than 50), like in *W.csv*.

Is there an efficient way that (for each date) populates the right weights to any currency that has any, and leaves the others at 0? The tricky part is dealing with dates when there are not enough currencies (thus *top_n.csv* has less than n currencies, and *weights.csv* has nans in the respective positions).

*W.csv* lools like:

```
Date        bitcoin ethereum    bitcoin-cash    ripple  litecoin    dash    neo nem monero  ethereum-classic    iota    qtum    omisego lisk    cardano zcash   bitconnect  tether  stellar    ....
Aug 12, 2016    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    ....
Aug 11, 2016    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    ....
Aug 10, 2016    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    ....
Aug 09, 2016    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    ....
```

My target is to result to a DataFrame that looks like *W_all_target*, which I attach as would not appear correctly (I have edited it by hand for this question).

I have saved three indicative CSVs as it will help to examine them.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1olx9ARI0XP5mqbqF1pfRfJyl9wIEWyZj

I am still learning, so I understand this may be a simple question. Sincere thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 0**
This is to accommodate the zeros and nans

```
dates = top_n.index.repeat(top_n.shape[1])
currs = top_n.values.ravel()
wghts = weights.values.ravel()
mask = currs != '0'

reshaped = pd.Series(wghts[mask], [dates[mask], currs[mask]]).unstack(fill_value=0)

W.update(reshaped)
```

---

**Option 1**

```
reshaped = pd.concat([d.stack() for d in [top_n, weights]], axis=1) \
  .reset_index(1, drop=True).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack(fill_value=0)

reshaped

0           bitcoin  ethereum  ethereum-classic  litecoin  ripple  steem
Date                                                                    
2016-08-09    0.858     0.086             0.017     0.000    0.02  0.020
2016-08-10    0.853     0.093             0.000     0.016    0.02  0.018
2016-08-11    0.856     0.092             0.000     0.016    0.02  0.016
2016-08-12    0.859     0.089             0.000     0.016    0.02  0.015
```

---

**Option 2**

```
reshaped = pd.Series(
    weights.values.ravel(),
    [top_n.index.repeat(top_n.shape[1]), top_n.values.ravel()]
).unstack(fill_value=0)

reshaped

            bitcoin  ethereum  ethereum-classic  litecoin  ripple  steem
Date                                                                    
2016-08-09    0.858     0.086             0.017     0.000    0.02  0.020
2016-08-10    0.853     0.093             0.000     0.016    0.02  0.018
2016-08-11    0.856     0.092             0.000     0.016    0.02  0.016
2016-08-12    0.859     0.089             0.000     0.016    0.02  0.015
```

---

Then you should be able to update `W` with

```
W.update(reshaped)

W

            bitcoin  ethereum  bitcoin-cash  ripple  litecoin  dash  neo  nem  monero  ethereum-classic  iota  qtum  omisego  lisk  cardano  zcash  bitconnect  tether  stellar
Date                                                                                                                                                                           
2016-08-12    0.859     0.089             0    0.02     0.016     0    0    0       0             0.000     0     0        0     0        0      0           0       0        0
2016-08-11    0.856     0.092             0    0.02     0.016     0    0    0       0             0.000     0     0        0     0        0      0           0       0        0
2016-08-10    0.853     0.093             0    0.02     0.016     0    0    0       0             0.000     0     0        0     0        0      0           0       0        0
2016-08-09    0.858     0.086             0    0.02     0.000     0    0    0       0             0.017     0     0        0     0        0      0           0       0        0
```

Comment: Feel free to unaccept until you are satisfied. You need to filter zero out. I can’t show at the moment. I’m not at a computer

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I have been trying to do this with lambda functions or a list comprehension but I am not sure how exactly.

Comment: Easiest way would be to use a Boolean mask on the raveled array

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide an example with the missing data?

Comment: I updated the answer with **Option 0**  Hope that helps.  Keep in mind I tested `!= '0'` because when I parsed the `top_n` dataframe, I got zeros as strings.  Your zeros may be integers.  Just pay attention.